# Torch.gesv B should be 2 dimensional

Tags: lua, torch

I just start taking the oxford machine learning course and I am new in lua and torch.

I am trying to solve a simple linear equation problem with torch.
The problem is like AX = B

However, I am not able to this because B is just a 1-D tensor (a vector). I think the case of B being a vector should be a common. And duplicating B into a 2-D tensor is wasteful.

```
B = torch.Tensor({0.1623, 0.0545})
A = torch.Tensor({{0.1303, -0.0003},{-0.0003, 0.1133}})
X = torch.gesv(B,A)
```

And I will get:

```
bad argument #2 to '?' (B should be 2 dimensional at
/Users/yiranzhang/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorLapack.c:79)
stack traceback:
[C]: at 0x0af6e890
[C]: in function 'gesv'
[string "xxx = torch.gesv(B,A)"]:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
...rs/yiranzhang/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:648: in function 'repl'
...hang/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x010ae382e0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: B = B:view(-1, 1). A view wont duplicate it, it will share the same memory.

Comment: this works! Thanks @smhx!